# How can I specify start date and end date when loading events in fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm loading the events using:

```
events: {url: "url" }
```

"url" return json data.
What I want to do is to specify the start and end parameters of this url (Fullcalendar specify them to the current date).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
events: {
        url: '/myfeed.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            startDate: 'someDate',
            endDate: 'someEndDate'
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
        }
    }
```

Ref: [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/)

Comment: O.K this is good but I want to replace start, end parameters the FullCalendar set when getting json data.